# Flatten TupleViews using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Ok, SwiftUI was released this week so we're all n00bs but... I have the following test code:

```
var body: some View {
    switch shape {
    case .oneCircle:
        return ZStack {
            Circle().fill(Color.red)
        }
    case .twoCircles:
        return ZStack {
            Circle().fill(Color.green)
            Circle().fill(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

which produces the following error:

*Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types*

This happens because the first ZStack is this type:

```
ZStack<ShapeView<Circle, Color>>
```

and the second is this type:

```
ZStack<TupleView<(ShapeView<Circle, Color>, ShapeView<Circle, Color>)>>
```

How do I deal with this in SwiftUI? Can they be flattened somehow or be made to conform to the same type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to fix this is to use the type eraser `AnyView`:

```
var body: some View {
    switch shape {
    case .oneCircle:
        return AnyView(ZStack {
            Circle().fill(Color.red)
        })
    case .twoCircles:
        return AnyView(ZStack {
            Circle().fill(Color.green)
            Circle().fill(Color.blue)
        })
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE

I add the following to answer the commenters who are asking why this is needed.

One commenter says

> ZStack is still a View, right?

Actually, no. `ZStack` by itself is not a `View`. `ZStack<SomeConcreteView>` is a `View`.

The declaration of `ZStack` looks like this:

```
public struct ZStack<Content> : View where Content : View
```

`ZStack` is generic. That means that `ZStack` by itself is not a type. It is a “[type constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_constructor)”.

The idea of a type constructor is not usually discussed in the Swift community. A type constructor is, essentially, a function that runs at compile time. The function takes one or more *types* as arguments and returns a type.

`ZStack` is a type constructor that takes one argument. If you ‘call’ `ZStack` repeatedly with different arguments, it returns different answers. This is what Robert Gummesson shows in his question:

> This happens because the first ZStack is this type:
>
> ```
> ZStack<ShapeView<Circle, Color>>
> ```
>
> and the second is this type:
>
> ```
> ZStack<TupleView<(ShapeView<Circle, Color>, ShapeView<Circle, Color>)>>
> ```

In the first case, the program ‘calls’ `ZStack` with the argument `ShapeView<Circle, Color>` and gets back a type as the answer. In the second case, the program ‘calls’ `ZStack` with a different argument, `TupleView<(ShapeView<Circle, Color>, ShapeView<Circle, Color>)>`, and so it gets back a different type as the answer.

The declaration `var body: some View` says that the `body` method returns a specific, concrete type (to be deduced by the compiler) that conforms to the `View` protocol. Since the two ‘calls’ to `ZStack` return different concrete types, we must find a way to convert them both to a single common type. That is the purpose of `AnyView`. Note that `AnyView` is **not** generic, which is to say, it is not a type constructor. It is just a plain type.

Comment: This answer 'works' but can someone weigh in if it's correct and if so, why this works?

Comment: I have the same error as op, but don't understand why is this needed. ZStack is still a View, right? And body property's type is some View....so, it should work as along as a View is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Group which is logical container so won't change anything visual.

```
 var body: some View {
    Group {
     switch shape {
     case .oneCircle:
        return ZStack {
            Circle().fill(Color.red)
        }
     case .twoCircles:
        return ZStack {
            Circle().fill(Color.green)
            Circle().fill(Color.blue)
        }
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But i stumbled upon it, and the now the correct way to do it, would be with a `@ViewBuilder` annotation (notice the missing `return`):

```swift
    @ViewBuilder var body: some View {
        switch shape {
        case .oneCircle:
            ZStack {
                Circle().fill(Color.red)
            }
        case .twoCircles:
            ZStack {
                Circle().fill(Color.green)
                Circle().fill(Color.blue)
            }
        }
    }
```

Or in this specific case, factor out the `ZStack`:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            switch shape {
            case .oneCircle:
                Circle().fill(Color.red)
            case .twoCircles:
                Circle().fill(Color.green)
                Circle().fill(Color.blue)
            }
        }
    }
```